# Draw A Line Between Two Location - WhirlyGlobe

Tags: ios

I'm working on an IOS application in which I'm using WhirlyGlobe (http://code.google.com/p/whirlyglobe/). This API is entirely new to me.

Can someone please help me to, draw line between 2 locations(Latitude,Langitude) using code ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that currently if you grab the "master" branch of the project, there isn't functionality to do that.  However, the development branch has such a thing, and more.  Take a look at this blog post that has a screen shot of lines being drawn from one location to another:

http://mousebirdconsulting.blogspot.ca/2013/01/whirlyglobe-component-21-beta1.html

You can download and compile the development branch from github, or get a binary distribution, the latest which is here:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/29069465/WhirlyGlobe-MaplyComponentDistribution_2_1_beta2.zip

You'll benefit by going through the header files and learning how it works anyway, so while you're looking for how this is done, you'll see a lot more interesting stuff.

There are many things I haven't done yet with WhirlyGlobe, and if I get to try this one out soo

Answer (score 0):

You can use MaplyShapeGreatCircle in MaplyShape.h and set the height close to 0.0 .

Comment: @andrew Hoyer ,@suryavel ,@Lucky_one : Hi there.please help me with this. I have started working on Whirly Globe Maply component tester app .(Great Framework by steve). I want to know on how we can add custom overlays and button on it to open a new view.. If you have done it then please guide me.code snipet will help too. and please if you can answer this too : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17270534/image-getting-stretched-when-creating-mbtiles-using-tilemills-to-use-as-an-image.