# Image getting stretched when creating MBTiles using TileMills to use as an Image on Whirly Globe Framework

Tags: iphone, mapbox, tilemill

I am struck with issue .

I want to use My personal Image as an image on whirly globe.I used a Jpeg file and changed into .tiff file and added to Tile Mills as a Layer (Following the rules specified in the crash course of tile mills).Now i am facing an issue while exporting the image as MbTiles .
I looked into this [Link](http://code.google.com/p/whirlyglobe/wiki/Imagery) for taking reference on what should be  'Dimensions' of the image to be used on whirly globe.

Right now i have an image whose dimensions are 10184X7638. But this image is not able to wrap the complete Whirly Globe.
Please guide me on

1. what the dimensions should be there of the image to be used for whirly globe.
2. can i use this values while creating a frame for the image as the image gets strected when is added to the globe .**Image1**
   [image].

This is the Image i am talking about it has a dimensions of 10184 X 7638 pixels and when i select these bounds as specified Image1 (-180,-85.11,180,85).then i get this **Image2**
[image]. Here you can see the image is not able to cover the complete bounds and hence the globe also is not fully wrapped with this image.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The image is less about dimensions and more about mapping it to geographic coordinates so that it can completely cover the globe. You need to make sure the image takes up your whole TileMill map if you want it to completely cover the globe in WhirlyGlobe.

Comment: Thanxs for the answer.I have a question on how can i check whether the image takes up my whole tileMill map? Are you saying that i check that on the image preview on tile mill ?    Can you provide me a link for that as when i change the dimensions of the image to be used then  it need to  cover the bounds(-180,-85.011,180,85.11) . I am attaching the image and upadating my answer on what issue i am facing right now.I am talking about Image 2 here and the extra white space left which need to be covered and how to do that?? please guide me if i going wrong. Thanks

Comment: You will need to use something like `gdalwarp` to geo-rectify your image to a globe in the proper projection. This is a good start: https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/reprojecting-geotiff/